# Modify the response size of Google Cloud Datastore API requests

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google Cloud Datastore, to store some data. When trying to extract all entities from my "Kind", through the API into GAS code, I realized that the API extracts 300 entities each time. To extract the totality of entities, I used the "cursor" option to fetch the next batch where the previous stopped.

Is there any way to extract all entities (or at least more than 300) at once?

While trying to find an answer in the web, I did not find any specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max number of entities you can update/upsert in one go via [Datastore's Data API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/) is 500 but if you use a lookup operation you could potentially fetch 1000 entities (as long as they are collectively under 10MB for the transaction) as listed under the ["Limits" section of Datastore's reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

However, you might be able to leverage the export/import endpoints of [Datastore's Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/) to export/import data in bulk. [Check out the guide for more information](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).

Comment: I have already used import/export data into datastore, and it functioned without prob for my data. The limitation of 300  results I had, was for a SELECT * query. Does the 500 limiit concern rather transactions (insert, update, delete or upsert)?

Comment: Yes. Insert, Update, Delete and Upsert are part of the Data API.

Comment: But lookUp allows up to 1000 entities, but you need to have all the entity keys for the request (and the total size of all entities must be under 10MB for the transaction).

Comment: Ok thanks :) In the [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=fr#p/datastore/v1/), I tested successfully **lookup** for a specific entity to search, but I haven' found **lookupbatch**. Does this command implementation depend on code language? For instance, there seems to be for php  [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.45.2/datastore/transaction?method=lookupBatch).

Comment: It is possible to add in the **lookup** query, as match as _"path"_ properties as the number of entities to fetch, but it is not really scalable...